# How to change the Text Format in Task description in Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, formatting, tasks, microsoft-outlook-2016

**What I want to do**

- I want to format the text description of a task in Outlook 2016. For instance, use bulleted lists or format some important text as bold.

**What's wrong (how to reproduce)**

- When I create a new task (Ctrl+Shift+K), the text description is just plain text. When I click on the ribbon tab "Format Text", then all buttons besides Paste, Find, and Select are grayed out.
- Similarly, (from experience in earlier versions) I would expect that when typing * + Space the text would automatically be formatted as a bulleted list. This does not happen.

**What I tried already (additional info)**

- When creating an email (and not a task), I can format the mail body. File > Options > Mail > Compose messages in this format is set to "HTML". I also tried "Rich Text".
- This is a full install of Office, including Word 2016.

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to format the Subject field? You can't put anything but plain text in there.

Comment: I checked this, and you definitely can do it with 2016 - http://i.stack.imgur.com/NLmVC.png My compose format is set to HTML.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that you cannot format the subject. But I cannot format the message body of a task either (where your example shows "Works well for me").