# Insert table in Task in Outlook 2016 Task is not possible

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I have a strange issue with an Outlook 2016. It seams to be similar to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1100069/how-to-change-the-text-format-in-task-description-in-outlook-2016), but as there is no answer there I try again here:

At one of my virtual computers an Outlook 2016 does not allow me to create tasks with a table in the body: The button "Insert table" is greyed out.
[image]

As you see clearly from the screenshot, the cursor IS in the body section.
Other formatting (bold, bullets, color) are possible, just not inserting a table.

On other computers with the same Outlook version I can add tables. This has to be some strange setting here. The mail preferences are set to "HTML" and this issue does not occur for mails and calendar entries, only for tasks.

Can anybody advice what to do to change this behaviour?

Comment: Did you try repairing Office or even reinstalling Office?  Uninstall, restart, install and update.

Comment: I was not 100% accurate: It is not only one client, it is two complete environments... other environment do not have that problem though...

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test on my outlook 2016 (version as shown in the below figure), I can successfully add tables when creating tasks. In order to prevent other problems caused by the version is not updated, please **make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version**.

[image]

[image]

> On other computers with the same Outlook version I can add tables.

On the other hand, I noticed that this problem seems to occur only in Outlook on your current computer. As John mentioned, It is recommended that you could try to [**fix the Office application**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). If it doesn't work, please **uninstall and reinstall Office** to check whether the problem still exists.

Hope the above help!

Comment: I am sorry, I was not 100% accurate in the description: This happens in ALL Outlook- Clients in two different environments. It does not happen in other environments. Your answer "works for me" does not really help, as it works for me as well... just not in the environment where I need it to work...

Comment: Do this issue occur with all Outlook clients in an environment? If so, is there any difference between this environment and other environment, such as some changes in registry, some add-ins or others?